# Fastest way to convert unsigned char 8 bits to actual numbers

Tags: c++, micro-optimization

I am using an `unsigned char` to store 8 flags. Each flag represents the corner of a cube. So `00000001` will be corner 1 `01000100` will be corners 3 and 7 etc. My current solution is to `&` the result with 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 and 128, check whether the result is not zero and store the corner. That is, `if (result & 1) corners.push_back(1);`. Any chance I can get rid of that 'if' statement? I was hoping I could get rid of it with bitwise operators but I could not think of any.

> A little background on why I want to get rid of the if statement. This *cube* is actually a Voxel which is part of a grid that is at least 512x512x512 in size. That is more than 134 million Voxels. I am performing calculations on each one of the Voxels (well, not exactly, but I won't go into too much detail as it is irrelevant here) and that is a lot of calculations. And I need to perform these calculations per frame. Any speed boost that is minuscule per function call will help with these amount of calculations. To give you an idea, my algorithm (at some point) needed to determine whether a float was negative, positive or zero (within some error). I had if statements in there and greater/smaller than checks. I replaced that with a fast float to int function and shaved of a quarter of a second. Currently, each frame in a 128x128x128 grid takes a little more than 4 seconds.

Comment: There may be other ways of writing this, but I don't think you'll get much faster than what you already have (**although really you ought to be profiling: how much of your overall runtime is this code taking?**).  Fundamentally, you need to push a non-constant number of objects into a data structure, and there's no way to do that without conditionals.

Comment: I am taking an average of the calculations per frame and currently using that as a measure. I completely agree that I should be using a profiler. I currently do not have access to one, the only free one I know that I found here on SO (for windows) is `Very Sleepy`. I am going to add timers before and after the function calls, but like I said, I got a simple timer already set up measuring how long it takes per frame and taking an average over several frames.

Comment: @Samursa: It's good to know that you believe in the power of profiling!  But the corollary is, you really shouldn't be worrying about the speed of this loop until you know for a fact that it's a problem.

Comment: Agreed. I will do that and will update the question as soon as I can. I was going to refrain from asking this question as I realize there are quite a few `how can I make this faster` questions here without profiling. But I thought that since I am calling it so many times, (twice per Voxel) and have isolated it (the loop is simply iterating over all Voxels and calling the function which contains these conditionals) that I should probably ask if there is a faster way.

Comment: until you can prove that this code is taking more than, say, 10% of your runtime, then focus your attention elsewhere!  Even at 10%, if you could somehow optimise this loop down to nothing, you'll only make your overall code 1.1x faster.  Don't sacrifice the readability of your code!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider a different approach to it entirely: there are only 256 possibilities for different combinations of flags. Precalculate 256 vectors and index into them as needed.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > corners(256);
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    std::vector<int>& v = corners[i];
    if (i & 1) v.push_back(1);
    if (i & 2) v.push_back(2);
    if (i & 4) v.push_back(4);
    if (i & 8) v.push_back(8);
    if (i & 16) v.push_back(16);
    if (i & 32) v.push_back(32);
    if (i & 64) v.push_back(64);
    if (i & 128) v.push_back(128);
}

for (int i = 0; i < NumVoxels(); ++i) {
    unsigned char flags = GetFlags(i);
    const std::vector& v = corners[flags];

    ... // do whatever with v
}
```

This would avoid all the conditionals *and* having push_back call `new` which I suspect would be more expensive anyway.

Comment: +1: Assuming the OP's code allows for this, then this is probably the best solution.

Comment: That is a great solution! I will substitute my code with your solution and leave it at that until I can profile as Oli suggested.

Answer (score 1):

[Hackers's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/), first page:

```
x & (-x) // isolates the lowest set bit
x & (x - 1) // clears the lowest set bit
```

Inlining your `push_back` method would also help (better create a function that receives all the flags together).

Usually if you need performance, you should design the whole system with that in mind. Maybe if you post more code it will be easier to help.

EDIT: here is a nice idea:

```
unsigned char LOG2_LUT[256] = {...};
int t;
switch (count_set_bits(flags)){
    case 8:     t = flags; 
                flags &= (flags - 1);       // clearing a bit that was set
                t ^= flags;                 // getting the changed bit
                corners.push_back(LOG2_LUT[t]);
    case 7:     t = flags; 
                flags &= (flags - 1);       
                t ^= flags;                 
                corners.push_back(LOG2_LUT[t]);
    case 6:     t = flags; 
                flags &= (flags - 1);       
                t ^= flags;                 
                corners.push_back(LOG2_LUT[t]);
    // etc...
};
```

`count_set_bits()` is a very known function: http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetTable

Comment: This won't help that much; the issue is the conditionals controlling the data-structure insertion, which cannot be avoided.

Comment: @Oli at least it reduces 8 sure conditionals to an average of 4.

Comment: That's a fair point.  Although without profiling, it's impossible to know whether this benefit will be cancelled by the CPU branch predictor, etc.

Comment: In fact, you've just moved the conditionals elsewhere.  The OP's code will have deterministically performed 8 tests, whereas yours will need a conditional to know when to stop!

Comment: @Oli nope. In the first method I proposed number of iterations would be equal to the number of set bits (4 on average).

Answer (score 1):

If there's some operation that needs to be done if the bit is set and not if it's not, it seems you'll have to have a conditional of some kind somewhere. If it could be expressed as a calculation somehow, you could get around it like this, for example:

```
numCorners = ((result >> 0) & 1) + ((result >> 1) & 1) + ((result >> 2) & 1) + ...
```

Comment: I don't require the number of corners... yet, however this is a very useful tidbit as I require counting corners down the line +1

Comment: @Samaursa Glad it'll be handy. I just meant it as an example though since I don't know what you're going to do with your `corners` collection. This is just one of the rare cases where conditionals can truly be gotten rid of.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, it's not "pretty", but it works.

```
(result & 1)   && corners.push_back(1);
(result & 2)   && corners.push_back(2);
(result & 4)   && corners.push_back(3);
(result & 8)   && corners.push_back(4);
(result & 16)  && corners.push_back(5);
(result & 32)  && corners.push_back(6);
(result & 64)  && corners.push_back(7);
(result & 128) && corners.push_back(8);
```

it uses a seldom known feature of the C++ language: the boolean shortcut.

Comment: That won't avoid the conditionals at the CPU level.

Comment: And it will compile to exacly the same code as the code in question.

Comment: @Oli actually, by the description of the OP, there is no way to avoid the comparisons at the CPU level.

Answer (score 0):

I've noted a similar algorithm in the OpenTTD code. It turned out to be utterly useless: you're faster off by *not* breaking down numbers like that. Instead, replace the iteration over the `vector<>` you have now by an iteration over the bits of the byte. This is far more cache-friendly.

I.e.

```
unsigned char flags = Foo(); // the value you didn't put in a vector<>
for (unsigned char c = (UCHAR_MAX >> 1) + 1; c !=0 ; c >>= 1)
{
  if (flags & c) 
    Bar(flags&c);
}
```